Not saving total price for orders
I tried to implement saving total price in orders but it`s returning an issue like before saving everything is good, but after it debug returning null
protected function createOrder($order_data) {
$user = user_load_by_mail($order_data['Email']);
if (!$user) {
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $order_data['Customer'],
        'mail' => $order_data['Email'],
        'status' => 1,
    ]);
    $user->save();
}

// Get currency code and amount
$splitAmount = $this->getCurrencyCode($order_data['Total']);
$formatted_value = number_format((float) $splitAmount['value'], 6, '.', '');

// Create the order
$order = Order::create([
    'type' => 'default',
    'state' => $order_data['Status'],
    'uid' => $user->id(),
    'order_number' => $order_data['ID'],
    'mail' => $user->getEmail(),
    'placed' => strtotime($order_data['Date']),
    'overridden_unit_price' => TRUE,
]);

// Create a Price object and set it to the order
$amount = new Price($formatted_value, $splitAmount['currency_code']);
$order->set('total_price', $amount);
dd($order->get('total_price')->getValue());
$order->save();
// $order = Order::load($order->id());

// Debug the total price after saving
dd($order->get('total_price')->getValue());

// Debug the total price to check the result
// dd($order->get('total_price')->getValue());
}
first debug
 array:1 [▼

0 => array:2 [▼
"number" => "1107000.000000"
"currency_code" => "LBP"
]
]
and the second one
' [] '

I'd imagine that there's existing code in the commerce modules that calculate the total price based on the referenced line items on the order. As it looks like you haven't set any so that's probably why its changing

Ok, thank you I will check how to do it

The order module's OrderStorage service always recalculates the order total right before an order is saved in doOrderPreSave(). This recalculation entails setting the price to NULL and then preparing a new price object for it based on any order items or adjustments on the order. If there are none, which is true of your order, the price will be saved as NULL, meaning no total price could be determined. In your case, the proper solution would be to add items and / or adjustments to your order object to represent the charges you are actually trying to assess.

Thank you!  I will check your answer!
